# Postfix can't send mails to google server -> FROM GOOGLE SERVER

Tags: debian, postfix, gmail, google-compute-engine

Hy, i have a "compute engine" hosted by google.
When i try to send an email via postfix, it doesn't work.

Error log says:

> postfix/smtp[16416]: 16C5820035: to=< some_gmail_mailadress@gmail.com>,
>   relay=none, delay=60, delays=0.15/0.02/60/0, dsn=4.4.1,
>   status=deferred (connect to
>   alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4003:c01::1b]:25: Network is
>   unreachable)

When i try to ping the hostname or it's ip adress, it works fine. 
Is this some kind of misconfiguration?

Regards, Chris

Comment: Ping only tests one thing: whether or not a specific type of ICMP packet can get through. It cannot be used to test SMTP. Check all firewall rules between postfix and your mail destination.

Comment: Does Google allow port 25 connections within their own infrastructure to Google SMTP servers? Eliminate that as a possibility. Many ISPs/Hosts do not allow that.

Answer (score 2):

Google doesn't allow outbound connections to send email. The ports 25, 465 and 587 are blocked. You will need to use a third party (like Sendgrid) to send mail. More info can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/